# Encrypting/Decrypting with AES and storing information in text file

Tags: java, encryption, file-io, cryptography

I have been working on my own little project, where I am trying to make a simple password manager. The problem I'm having currently, is getting it to work in a way so that when ran, it saves the encrypted password to a file, then when ran another time, you can call it and it will be decrypted, showing you your password for the username you call.

For something I would like to add on to the program later, I do need to keep the encryption/decryption methods separate.

The current error is:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.*;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class PasswordManager3
{

    static String key = "SimplePasswordMg";
    static String password1 = "";
    static String password2 = "";
    static String username = "";


    public static void main(String[] args) 
             throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, 
             BadPaddingException, IOException 
    {

        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        System.out.println("Enter New to input a new password, or Retrieve to retrieve an old password:");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = scanner1.nextLine();

        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("New")) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a username: ");
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            username = scanner2.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a password: ");
            Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            password1 = scanner3.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter your password again: ");
            Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
            password2 = scanner4.nextLine();

            if (password1.equalsIgnoreCase(password2)) {

                Files.write(Paths.get(username + ".txt"), encrypt(password1, cipher, aesKey));
                System.out.println("Your password has been stored.");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("The passwords you entered did not match. Exiting password manager.");
            }

        }

        else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Retrieve")) {

            System.out.println("Please enter the username you would like to retrieve the password for: ");
            Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
            username = scanner5.nextLine();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(username + ".txt"));
            String encryptedpass = in.readLine();
            byte[] encryptedpass2 = encryptedpass.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(decrypt(encryptedpass2, cipher, aesKey));
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("You entered an incorrect option, program exited.");
        }

    }

     public static byte[] encrypt(String str, Cipher cipher, Key aesKey) 
             throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException 
     {

          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);

          byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));

          return encrypted;
     }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] byte1, Cipher cipher, Key aesKey) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 

    {

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(byte1));
        return decrypted;
    }

}
```

Comment: Encrypted data is not text, and a file containing it is not a text file, and should not be named `.txt`.

Comment: Thank you @EJP, I'm not quite sure why I was storing as a text file, I guess it was pretty late and I wasn't really thinking about it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are not writing a text file.** Encrypted data is effectively random bits, and your `main` passes the return from `encrypt` directly to `Files.write(Path,byte[])` which writes it as binary.

When you read it back in with `FileReader` it uses the default encoding for your platform, which you didn't identify, and sometimes your user's environment, which may or may not mangle some bytes; using `readLine()` may discard part of the data, and encoding it with `getBytes("UTF-8")` when it was never valid characters to start with is about 99.6% certain to mangle whatever is left. As a result the value you pass to `decrypt` is completely wrong, and can't be decrypted.

The easy, symmetric fix is **use `File.readAllBytes(Path)` to read the (whole) file as binary**, and decrypt the `byte[]` value that returns.

Alternatively, if you really want text files for some reason (and I don't see any), you need to first encode the encrypted value into a textual form and write that, probably with a line terminator added, then read it back (as a line if you chose that) and decode it before decrypting. Base64 and hexadecimal (abbreviated hex) are the two most common methods of textually encoding binary data.

**Also:** using a key which is all printable ASCII and contains even parts of English words hugely weakens your encryption, from the nominal 128 bits to something more like 20-30 bits, which can be easily broken by any half-competent attacker. Using any hardcoded key is also a danger, although this is a harder problem and there is no single, easy and good solution.

And you are using AES in ECB mode by default. Using ECB for passwords (and almost anything else) is a bad idea; to learn why google "ECB penguin" and "Adobe password breach" and/or see

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/can-ecb-mode-really-leak-some-characters

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11456/what-does-it-mean-if-second-half-of-8-char-string-encrypted-in-3des-is-always-id

Comment: Thank you so much. It was late and so even I am not sure why I was storing it as a text file. Using the `File.readAllBytes(Path)` fixed all of my issues. Thank you so much!